# showing class summary beside category in asp.net core api

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

[image]I am developing web API in ASP.NET Core.
I am looking for a way for showing class summary beside category in asp.net core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This

> ```
>         services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
>         {
>             var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
>             var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
>             c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath, includeControllerXmlComments: true);
>         });
> ```

Comment: I used  **c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath)** but it didn't work

Comment: IncludeControllerXmlComments parameter solves your problem